Applying for ESTA after rejection but subsequent B visa grant
I am a UK citizen and was refused an ESTA almost 10 years ago due to answering a security question incorrectly.  I subsequently applied for, and was granted, a US visa.  Can I apply for an ESTA when my current visa expires?  I have a new UK passport and new number.  I only travel to the US on holiday, so don’t I need or want a visa, if I can avoid getting one.

Yes you can apply for ESTA.  Your prior denial might result in denial of this one, and, more likely, will at least cause delay because of "manual" evaluation, but there's nothing mentioned in the question that will cause automatic denial.
If the ESTA is denied, of course, you will need to apply for another B visa; the chance of that being granted is probably very high given your history.  Because the ESTA may require a few days, and a subsequent B visa application may be necessary, you will probably want to apply a month or two before you plan to buy your tickets.

The question in the Esta I answered wrongly was the terrorism question.  I simply ticked the wrong box!  Is that an automatic denial for a new ESTA?
